# How to simulate a shift press in C# code?

Tags: c#, keyboard, keycode, shift

I'm using thiis code to simulate key presses or key ups:

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern void keybd_event(byte bVk, byte bScan, uint dwFlags, uint dwExtraInfo);
const uint KEYEVENTF_KEYUP = 0x0002;
const uint KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY = 0x0001;

// Key up
keybd_event((byte)Convert.ToInt32("A0"), 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP | 0, 0);

// Key down
keybd_event((byte)Convert.ToInt32("A0"), 0, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY | 0, 0);
```

According to [this table](http://delphi.about.com/od/objectpascalide/l/blvkc.htm), left-shift has the keycode A0.

For some reason the code above isn't working. Does anyone know why? Thanks a lot for the help! :)

Comment: You'll need to learn the basics to tackle hex.  This is good: http://www.charlespetzold.com/code/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using [keycode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375731(v=vs.85).aspx) is not necessary then you can use `Keys.LShiftKey` from [KEY enumeration of System.Windows.Forms Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keys.aspx).

Further using

```
keybd_event((byte)0xA0, 0x45, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP | 0, 0);
```

is not a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [here](http://www.mods.com.au/budapi_docs/Virtual%20Key%20Codes.htm) for keys.

```
 keybd_event(160, 0, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY | 0, 0);
```